# React renderComponent Requires DOMElement

Tags: reactjs

One of the JSX supported attributes is the html tag: 
http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html

However, when using React.renderComponent, a DOMelement is required as a container. So when rendering JSX with an html tag, what DOMelement should be used as a container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "document".

like this:

```
react.renderComponent(<App />, document);
```

Comment: document.documentElement works currently, but using document throws an error unless you're using server rendering.

Comment: yes, it should use "renderComponentToString" or "renderComponentStaticMarkup" to work on server.

Comment: Thanks fellas. I'm looking into it. Neither solution is working perfectly. I am rendering from the server, but I'm trying to render on the client as soon as the page is displayed. I think both of you have answered my initial question, but I'm afraid I still haven't solved the problem yet.

Comment: Please refer to my serverside rendering sample if you need. https://github.com/koba04/react-boilerplate/tree/serverside-rendering